# Possibly corrupt sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, corruption, corrupt, data-corruption

So I have [this SQLite3 database](https://download.straw-solutions.cz/brokenDb.sqlite). I've noticed a problem that when trying to select songs using the uid column, it does not return any rows; for example:

```
SELECT * FROM songs WHERE uid = 'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA=='
```

Even though a row with the given uid exists. Replacing the '=' with 'LIKE' returns the correct row.

I've been able to fix it using:

```
UPDATE songs SET uid = uid || ''
```

Is this a typical case of corrupt db? Or could it be an sqlite bug? How could this have happened?

Comment: Really need more information here. What's your table schema? What [type affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) does your uid column have? What types are the values you're actually storing in it if they're something else? Without any of that, all we can do is guess. Maybe the uid is a blob not a text value?

Comment: @Shawn You can get all the information from the disclosed SQLite database. I would answer your questions, but I've already got an answer (below) solving my problem and containing the information you've been asking for. You were right about the blob != text. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is an indication of corruption rather how **=** is handled.

For example consider the following :-

```
SELECT uid, 
    TRIM(uid) = 'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==' AS trim1match,
    TRIM(uid) = TRIM('yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==') AS trimbothmatch,
    CAST(uid AS TEXT) = 'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==' AS casttotextmatch,
    'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==' LIKE(uid) AS likematch,
    'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==' = uid AS reversematch
FROM songs 
WHERE trim(uid) = 'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA=='
```

The **`WHERE`** clause, using TRIM(uid) selects the appropriate row. The resultant output is :-

[image]

- Noting that `'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==' = uid AS reversematch` returns false, but all other comparisons return 1 i.e. true and thus a match.

### The Issue (uid stored as a BLOB)

The issue is that the **uid** column has a storage class of **BLOB** and thus a type affinity of **BLOB**. This can be seen by adding column that extracts the type of the column/row by using the **typeof** function e.g. :-

```
SELECT uid, typeof(uid),
    trim(uid) = 'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==' AS trim1match,
    trim(uid) = trim('yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==') AS trimbothmatch,
    CAST(uid AS TEXT) = 'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==' AS casttotextmatch,
    'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==' LIKE(uid) AS likematch,
    'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA==' = uid AS reversematch
FROM songs 
WHERE trim(uid) = 'yzoiaVuicn5ISq1+4DaKGbM3trht/z/ONNm+vA=='
```

results in :-

[image]

Hence converting the column to a type of TEXT explicitly (CAST) or implicitly (some functions such as TRIM) resolves the issue. Note that SUBSTR return bytes from a BLOB so will not convert the column type and hence `substr(uid,1)` doesn't work.

---

**Note**

Running the above less the where clause indicates that some rows have a column type of TEXT for the uid column, as per :-

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative and helpful answer. I didn't know string/blob disequality was a thing in SQLite. I've been generating some of the UID's using Qt's QUuid and casting to string and the blob ones were created by base64 encoding a hash which I did pass as QByteArray. I believe casting it to string will resolve my issue.